# want to write only certain types on the interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using TypeScript.
I have a question about how to use the TypeScript interface.
Is there a way to take and write only certain key types from the interface I'm using?
Actually, I can separate the type I'm trying to use, but I was wondering if there was a corresponding method during development.
Print out a brief example of my question.

```
interface Props {
 aType: number;
 bType: string;
 certainType : 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
}

interface PooProps {
  cType: boolean;
  wantType: any Method // Props certainType
}

function foo(value: PooProps){}

const result = foo({cType: true, wantType: 'a'}) //Type Ok
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type it as `Props['certainType']`.

```
interface PooProps {
  cType: boolean;
  wantType: Props['certainType']
}
```

Comment: Tthat's the answer I was looking for. Thanks to you, my knowledge has improved